# Client Side Validations and Rails4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I integrated client side validations with rails4 using the new branches available using the following gems

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.0.rc'
gem 'client_side_validations', github: "bcardarella/client_side_validations", :branch => "4-0-beta"
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', git: 'git://github.com/saveritemedical/client_side_validations-simple_form.git'
gem "jquery-rails"
```

I also added the required JavaScript as the following

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require rails.validations
//= require rails.validations.simple_form
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

I created this test form in order to see if it works

```
= simple_form_for(@post, :validate => true) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title, :required => true

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

of course in the model, it was

```
validates :title, presence: true
```

The problem is I can't figure our why it is not working, while JavaScript Console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

These gems involve a lot of configurations and ordering to be proper. Instead of explaining the whole procedure i can give you a link in SO where a similar problem was solved. Please do check it out and follow the same.

[ruby-on-rails client_side_validation simple_form javascript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180392/ruby-on-rails-client-side-validation-simple-form-javascript-error)

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

The problem appear to be in the order of the javascript, just change the order it will work fine