# Form is not getting submitted with unobtrusive javascript in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ujs

```
<%= form_for(current_user, url: update_my_profile_path, :method => :post, remote: true ) do |f| %>

   First Name: <%= f.text_field :firstname, value: current_user.firstname %>
   Last Name: <%= f.text_field :lastname, value: current_user.lastname %>
   Phone No. <%= f.text_field :phone, value: current_user.phone  %>

<%= f.submit  'update details', remote: true  %>
```

validation in my Javascript file :

```
 $("#personal_profile_update form").validate({

        rules: {
                firstname: { //validation rule },

                lastname: { //validation rule }

                }, // End of the rules

      messages: {    } // End of the messges section
});
```

Here validation works nicely. but when  i try to submit the form with remote: true option in both form & f.submit, it does not get submitted. 
once I remove this jquery.validate this form gets submitted with remote: true option.

is there any way to submit this form with remote: true option being applied validation rules active ???

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050669/rails-4-client-side-validation)  and also [Judge gem](https://github.com/joecorcoran/judge) is for client-side validation. [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) has a whole episode on using client-side-validation gem.