# The rails way of doing client side validation (Rails 4 with simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails and using Rails 4. I have started some forms for creating/editing some models and have added some validation which works fine on the server side.

I assumed that Rails would have something built in to handle client side validation - turns out it doesn't.

I have searched on google and found 'client_side_validation' which is no longer maintained and I don't think works in Rails 4 anyway.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious go to library for Rails client side validation. So what is the 'Rails way' of handling this? Roll your own? Duplicate the logic client side using jQuery? Use html5 validation and fall back to server side when it isn't their? Or is there a library (preferably one that works with simple_form) that I can just install and use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations), but is not longer maintained. Probably the best way is using some jQuery plugin like [jquery-validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Comment: I am considering using jquery. But I don't like that I would have to duplication my validation logic client side

Comment: Thats currently not true (Oct 2017). The client_side_validations are back and alive :)

Comment: @EduardoCobuci Did you try this gem on rails 5?

Answer (score 2):

***Rails 4 + Simple form :*** To install "Client side validations" with simple_form successfully, you should check for latest versions direct from Github with latest branch.

The released gems don't work with Rails >= 4.0

```
gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

Make sure your gem file does not use these versions

```
client-side Validation 3.2.5
client_side_validations-simple_form 2.1.0
```

These versions does not support rails 4.2.0

For more detail please check this link,
https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is in Rails 4 is to use the client side validation gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/rails4_client_side_validations

This guy here is using it: [Client Side Validations and Rails4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635847/client-side-validations-and-rails4)

Railscasts provides a good tutorial (Rails 3) on it here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations

Comment: That railscast is good but unfortunately a little out of date. I followed the link to the guy asking the question on stackoverflow - and the instructions worked. I just thought there would be a stable, standard rails way of doing this as it is so common

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a fork of the original client_side_vlaidations that is very active at the moment. I am using the latest version of simple_form, rails 4.1.8, and this [client_side_validations](https://github.com/tagliala/client_side_validations/tree/rails4). Simple setup with basic config.